# How to download Google Map for Offline Mode in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have integrated a Google Map in my Android application.
Now, i want to show a particular location in my application's Google Map in offline mode.

When i start my application and internet is there, Now, i want to download Google Map for a particular location. So, how can i do that ?

I have researched and found that we can save particular location for offline mode from default Map application in android and also referred some links mentioned below:
https://www.google.co.in/search?output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=google%20maps%20in%20offline%20mode%20android&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.75097201%2Cd.c2E%2Cpv.xjs.s.en.1GCsNs9pfB4.O&ion=1&biw=1366&bih=643&ech=1&psi=J_cTVOa7HoS_uATTnoGQCA.1410594602599.3&ei=J_cTVOa7HoS_uATTnoGQCA&emsg=NCSR&noj=1

So, please let me know how can we do that ?

Comment: Hello @DOWNVOTERS, Can you please tell me why did you down vote this question as well as answer? Whats wrong in this? Please tell me..

Answer (score -1):

According to their TOS, looks like you're not allowed to do it. See section 10.1.3, (b)

https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Btw, I am not a lawyer, so it's best you consult one to be sure.